# Unable to create HttpClient instance in console app, mvc 4 web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've installed nuGet package for web api and trying to create a HttpClient instance in console app (I added System.Net.Http reference), but I get a strange compile error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Aleksey_Chepovoi@epam.com\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication\Program.cs   14  21  ConsoleApplication

Already tried to restart VS 2012 and create a new console project.

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

The reference you are looking for is System.Net.Http
The only nuget package you need for HttpClient is this http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.0.20710.0

Just make sure you are either using .net 4.5 or .net 4 full.  The client profile of .net 4 will not work.

Answer (score 0):

System.Net.Http: The main NuGet package providing the basic HttpClient and related classes

System.Net.Http.Formatting: Adds support for serialization, deserialization as well as for many additional features building on top of System.Net.Http

System.Json: Adds support for JsonVaue which is a mechanism for reading and manipulating JSON documents

you may need these also. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee will give you basic idea about HttpClient